# Reading CSV files with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read in a .csv file with MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
csvread('out2.csv')
```

This is what out2.csv looks like:

```
03/09/2013 23:55:12,129.32,129.33
03/09/2013 23:55:52,129.32,129.33
03/09/2013 23:56:02,129.32,129.33
```

On windows I am able to read this exact same file with the xlsread function with no problems. I am currently on a linux machine. When I first used xlsread to read the file I was told "File is not in recognized format" so I switched to using csvread. However, using csvread, I get the following error message:

```
Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 2u) ==> /09/2013
23:55:12,129.32,129.33\n

Error in csvread (line 48)
m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c)
```

I think the '/' in the date is causing the issue. On windows, the 1st column is interpreted as a string. On linux it seems to be interpreted as a number, so it tries to read the number and fails at the backslash. This is what I think is going on at least. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: try [readtext](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946-readtext) instead of `csvread`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`csvread` can only read doubles, so it's choking on the date field. Use `textscan`.

```
fid = fopen('out2.csv');
out = textscan(fid,'%s%f%f','delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

date = datevec(out{1});
col1 = out{2};
col2 = out{3};
```

---

**Update (8/31/2017)**

Since this was written back in 2013, MATLAB's [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec) function has been updated to directly read dates and times. Now the code would look like this:

```
fid = fopen('out2.csv');
out = textscan(fid, '%{MM/dd/uu HH:mm:ss}D%f%f', 'delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid)

[date, col1, col2] = deal(out{:});
```

An alternative as mentioned by @Victor Hugo below (and currently my personal go-to for this type of situation) would be to use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) which will accept the same formatting string as `textscan` but assemble the results directly into a table object:

```
dataTable = readtable('out2.csv', 'Format', '%{MM/dd/uu HH:mm:ss}D%f%f')
dataTable.Properties.VariableNames = {'date', 'col1', 'col2'};

dataTable =

  3×3 table

           date             col1      col2 
    ___________________    ______    ______

    03/09/2013 23:55:12    129.32    129.33
    03/09/2013 23:55:52    129.32    129.33
    03/09/2013 23:56:02    129.32    129.33
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) for `csvread` clearly states:

> `M = csvread(filename)` reads a comma-separated value formatted file, `filename`. ***The file can only contain numeric values.***

Since `/` is neither a comma, nor a numeric value, it produces an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readtable`, as it will accept any input.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah xlsread requires Microsoft Excel to be installed, unless it is run in 'basic' mode and 'basic' mode only reads .xls .xlsx and .xlsm files.

Another alternative are a number of user-written functions posted on MATLAB's file exchange that will work on linux and are more flexible at reading non formatted content.

One example:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/75219-csv2cellfast-import-csv-files-on-machines-without-excel

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Please edit your answer and add an explanation that may be useful.