# Importing a csv file in Matlab with multiple types into a 2D array

Tags: matlab, parsing, csv, file-io

I am trying to import a CSV file in Matlab. The file contains integers, floats and a timestamp of the time taken. csvread or dlmread do not do the trick due to mixed file types.
On the other hand I tried textscan as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/matlab-import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types) but the whole data is put into a Nx1 array (with N being the number of lines in the csv file. 
The data is EEG data that I wish to perform some band bass filtering to it, but first I need to read the file in a 2D array. Any ideas?
P.S. I am using Matlab R2013a

Example file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/35z28dju163fg1j/EEG.csv)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading CSV files with MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613232/reading-csv-files-with-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not use Excel, this Question is a duplicate (comment of Eitan). Otherwise I would recommend to use xlsread, this uses excel com interface and is able to read everything excel can read.