# Importing csv file with time data

Tags: matlab, csv, text-parsing

I am trying to import csv file into MATLAB. However, I  am getting error when I use `csvread`. I also tried `importfile` and `importdata` function, but they did not work either. I shared data [via dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cos2mgm8z908vo/200611011.edf_Data.csv?dl=0). Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance.

First few lines of file:

```
Subject,Session,Epoch , Datapoint, ECG,POz,Fz,Cz,C3,C4,F3,F4,P3,P4,Tilt X,Tilt Y,Tilt Z,ESUTimestamp, SystemTimestamp, 
2006,200611011,0, 1, -18.92119,-71.56481,-82.09354,-56.73304,-58.59464,-79.89624,-58.50309,-99.61089,-67.78058,-61.52438,-230,-70,22,00:16:50:591,13:26:45:458
2006,200611011,0, 2, -17.91409,-71.56481,-79.04173,-54.50523,-54.71885,-81.39162,-50.81254,-96.86427,-70.16098,-57.31289,-231,-68,25,00:16:50:591,13:26:45:458
2006,200611011,0, 3, 
<snip>
```

Comment: Please tell which error you are getting and which code your are using.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613232/reading-csv-files-with-matlab
You cannot use csvread with files contaning non-numeric values.

Comment: First of all, your csv is not properly formatting, as you have an extra `,` at the end of the first row. That extra comma make things much harder since Matlab thinks that there is an extra column that the others rows do not have.

Comment: First, I tried `csvread` function by starting row 2. and it gave me Error using dlmread (line 139) error. Then I created `importfile` function by using Matlab import file wizard. Although I wait about 20 mins, it could not import the data. Finally, I tried to import data manually by using Matlab import file wizard.This is working, but it is taking more than 30 minutes to import one file. And I have 95 file like that. So, that will not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

`textscan` supports `datetime` format specifiers [starting with R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#R2014b).  The following command skips the header line and reads the data in according to the specified formats:

```
fid  = fopen('200611011.edf_Data.csv','r'); assert(fid~=-1)
tfmt = '%{HH:mm:ss:SSS}D';
C = textscan(fid,['%d%d%d%d%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%d%d%d' tfmt tfmt],...
    'HeaderLines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
```

If you don't have `datetime` support (R2014b or newer), read the time fields in as strings:

```
C = textscan(fid,['%d%d%d%d%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%d%d%d%s%s'],...
    'HeaderLines',1,'Delimiter',',');
```

Comment: Does not work: Error using textscan Badly formed format string.

Comment: @JaviV Made a note of R2014b requirement and provided `datetime` alternative (strings for the times).

Comment: @chappjc I got same mistake, which is Error using textscan Badly formed format string. And I am using Matblab R2014a.

Comment: @Ram That's expected. It's a new feature in **R2014b, not R2014a**. Use the second solution.