# Does the xlsread function in MATLAB require Excel?

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, xlsread

I have two computers with the same MATLAB code and same Excel file (.csv format). The code only works on the machine that has Excel. I can't think of any other differences.

Does a computer need Excel for xlsread to work? The error I'm getting is an unrecognized format.

If this is the case, are there any easy workarounds without getting Excel?

EDIT: It appears that Excel is not needed. Maybe the issue is that the file is a .csv? It is a format error after all. I just can't imagine why a file of the same format worked on my other computer.

SOLVED: The .csv file was the problem. For reading .csv files, the importdata() function of matlab proved to be really versatile.

Comment: A `csv` file is not, repeat **NOT**  an Excel file.  It is an ascii text file which happens to use a comma as a delimiter. Why are you using an Excel-reading function rather than any of the builtin text-file tools?

Comment: PLease read the posting guidelines and supply your actual code that is failing to read the file **and** a small, reproducible sample text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange,'basic')` will work without Excel installed on your machine.

Other additional arguments will require Excel to be installed.

Matlab can import character separated files natively though.

Comment: The file name is the only argument that I'm using.

Comment: Bung in the other ones in just to test. Perhaps the defaulting is different. But do try to parse the csv natively though.

Comment: I've tested with just the file name, the file name and the sheet, and also all four arguments. All return the same error. The same is true for when I try something like dlmread or csvread. I'm starting to think that maybe this is a file issue or my matlab is lacking some sort of functionality.

Comment: To eliminate one possibility, could you use the excel you do have to convert your csv to a native xls, and try that?

Comment: Wow, good call. It totally works when I save it as a .xlsx. With that being said, I actually made a mistake in my previous comment. csvread gives a different error, saying it has trouble reading the Numeric field in the first cell.

Comment: Your CSV error is probably because you have mixed data (numeric along with date and/or text).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613232/reading-csv-files-with-matlab/19613301#19613301) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/system-requirements-for-importing-spreadsheets.html)

> If your system has Excel® for Windows® installed, including the COM server (part of the typical installation of Excel):
>
> All MATLAB® import options support XLS, XLSX, XLSB, XLSM, XLTM, and XLTX formats.

...

> If your system does not have Excel for Windows installed, or the COM server is not available:
>
> All MATLAB import options read XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTM, and XLTX files.

However, if you are just trying to import a comma delimited ASCII file, then `xlsread` is way overkill and super slow. If your data is purely numeric, use [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) or [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html). If your data is mixed, then use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) instead.

Comment: Which is a good reason to switch to `R`,  where there are tools to read `.xl**` files without Excel, or OpenOffice for that matter, present.

Comment: Actually, it's a good reason to not use the proprietary `.xl**` format at all so that your data is freely portable and readable in a wide variety of languages.

Comment: Well put,  Craigm!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have never used `xlsread` on a computer without Excel, so I can't be sure. But according to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) Excel is not necessary; you only lose some functionality:

> `num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange,'basic')` reads data from the spreadsheet in basic import mode. If your computer does not have Excel for Windows®, `xlsread` automatically operates in `basic` import mode, which supports XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, and XLTM files.
>
> `basic` mode is the default for computers without Excel for Windows. In basic mode, `xlsread`:
>
> - Reads XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, and XLTM files only.
> - Does not support an `xlRange` input when reading XLS files. In this case, use `''` in place of `xlRange`.
> - Does not support function handle inputs.
> - Imports all dates as Excel serial date numbers. Excel serial date numbers use a different reference date than MATLAB® date numbers.

So, perhaps the problem is that you are calling `xlsread` with some options that are not supported in `basic` mode.

Comment: The file name is the only argument. I have also tried adding in some of the other arguments, using csvread, dlmread, etc. None of it has solved the issue.