# How to load a csv file as a datamatrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv

I try to load a csv file in matlab to use a certain column as a vector for a OLS estimation. However, my csv looks like:

```
    Date            KCFSI
13  2004-02-01  -0.67
14  2004-03-01  -0.58
15  2004-04-01  -0.57
16  2004-05-01  -0.49
17  2004-06-01  -0.67
...
```

and I want to have the the column `KCFSI` as a vector.

I tried:

```
x=fopen('kcfsi.csv');

kcfsi=x(:,2);
```

But I don't even get a matrix for my x. Just get as value : "14" for whatever reason. I want to have something like "2x100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvread` cannot open csv files containing non-Numeric values as stated in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html).

> The file must contain only numeric values.

So you should use `textscan` as explained in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613301/11756186

Alternatively you can use the [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) built-in function

```matlab
csvtable = readtable('kcfsi.csv');
kcfsi_array = csvtable.KCFSI; %Column vector with the content of the KCFSI column
```

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` returns a fileID,  not a matrix.
Use `A = readmatrix(filename)` or `M = csvread(filename)` instead.

Comment: @Dennis undefined function *what*

Comment: @Dennis, the function is `csvread` not `readcsv` "unfortunately" names does not commute. :)

Comment: @qwertz, you may want to specify that the `csvread` should start from the first row to ignore the header.